# Encriptacion html y js

Tags: javascript, html, seguridad, encriptación

quiero saber como encriptar una pagina html, que cuando miren el codigo html no se vea nada, y lo mimso con sus js.

Intente ponerle código a la pagina, pero si al ver el código fuente abrieron la información

```
pal=prompt('Introduce la clave','') ;
    if(pal!="clave123"){

        location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: ESTAS CONfundiendo los términos eso que buscas no es encriptar, se dice ofuscar

Comment: el navegador necesita el codigo. No puedes poner informacion sensible en el codigo, da igual si esta ofuscado y minificado

Comment: Como dicen en los comentarios el navegador requiere el código sí o sí y no es encriptar lo que harás, sino ofuscar, de todas formas acá te dejo un [link](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) que te permitirá ofuscar tu código javascript.

Comment: Todas las páginas html y el js de la misma son "públicos", es decir, que cualquiera con un navegador puede obtener todo el contenido,pero como dice el compañero arriba puedes usar diferentes herramientas para ofuscar el contenido de tu js. Para ello puedes hacerlo con diferentes herramientas. Te invito a que le eches un ojo a node y npm - https://nodejs.org/es/ - https://www.npmjs.com/ Con npm puedes instalar uglifyjs te dejo un artículo para que le resuelva tus dudas. - https://diego.com.es/comprimir-archivos-css-js-con-uglifycss-y-uglifyjs Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente queres encryptar el html podes usar CryptoJS, una vez desencriptado se ve el código en el inspector, pero si no conocen la clave supongo que vale.

```js
var secreto="U2FsdGVkX1+n17bqE1MxKKOH5cok3j64MQY0TTBGp5HXolT8IRdcW+QAGsFMLt/yrxN1DTuWzV2ihm3fzUy4JPahsNuymmtFmSJA+QgF6lTpyw7ouIZwVZMRSVvLOaTV";
$(function(){
  $("#dejameEntrar").on("click", function(){
    var pass = $("#clave").val();
    var desencryptado = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(secreto, pass).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    $("#asgard").html(desencryptado);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>L'Encriptau</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Heimdall">
    <input
      type="password"
      id="clave"
      name="clave"
      placeholder="Ingresa el Secret Key"
      value=""/>
    <button id="dejameEntrar">Enviar</button>
  </div>
  <div id="asgard">
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
</html>
```

PS: la clave es "Mi Clave Super$ecreta" sin comillas.

Para encryptar aquí va un snippet

```js
$(function(){
   $("#dameLaCrypto").on("click", function(){
    var elHtml = $("#elhtml").val();
    var laKey = $("#clave").val();
    var encrypteado = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt( elHtml, laKey).toString();
    $("#encrypteado").val(encrypteado);
    console.log(encrypteado, laKey);
  });    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>L'Encriptadeur</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="elhtml" placeholder="el HTML a encryptar" rows="5" cols="32"></textarea><br />
<input 
      type="password"
      id="clave"
      name="clave"
      placeholder="Ingresa el Secret Key"
      value=""/>
 <button id="dameLaCrypto">Enviar</button>
 <p>aqui debajo va la cadena encriptada</p>
 <textarea id="encrypteado" rows="5" cols="32"></textarea>
</body>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
</html>
```

En el ejemplo se usa el CDN, pero también podes importar la librería con npm o bower

https://github.com/brix/crypto-js