# ¿Cómo funciona la codificación porcentual y cómo decodificar la cadena %E4%F6%FC?

Tags: javascript

He observado esta linea de código:

```
document.write(unescape(''));
```

Donde dentro de las comillas `''` he observado una codificación infinita de, letras números así: `%E4%F6%FC`

Me pueden explicar para que sirve este método, como se emplea, como se codifica y como se puede leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una forma bastante näif de ocultar código, lo que va dentro de las comillas está "codificado" según el valor ASCII hexadecimal.

Por ejemplo: `%41` representa el número `0x41` en [hexadecimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_hexadecimal) (números en base 16) que en decimal (números en base 10) se traduce a `65` el cual es el código [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) de la letra `A`.

En este ejemplo uso los valores hexa codificados del texto "`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`" para cargar jQuery inyectando el texto del script en el documento con `document.write`.

Uso un TimeOut para esperar que cargue el jQuery antes de usarlo y luego se imprime "hola" en el div `mensaje`

```js
var t="%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%61%6A%61%78%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%61%70%69%73%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%61%6A%61%78%2F%6C%69%62%73%2F%6A%71%75%65%72%79%2F%32%2E%31%2E%31%2F%6A%71%75%65%72%79%2E%6D%69%6E%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E";
document.write(unescape(t));
console.log(unescape(t));
// espera de 2 segundos para que se cargue jquery
setTimeout(function(){$('#mensaje').text('hola');},2000);
```

```html
<div id="mensaje">
</div>
```

Para decodificar el texto, podes usar un console.log  ó algún sitio que haga el unencode online por ejemplo https://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/unescape.html

Comment: Excelente, la herramienta en linea fantástica, en fin de cuentas, lo que hace una codificación `unescape` es evitar que a la primera vista vea el código, pero en fin de cuentas no es seguro, porque se puede leer, no existe forma de que no se pueda descodificar verdad, esta alternativa afecta el rendimiento de un sitio web o no.

Comment: `document.write` para insertar scripts por el momento da un aviso `[Violation] Avoid using document.write().` lo que hace suponer que tal vez sea dejado de lado en el futuro. javascript se ejecuta del lado del cliente así que de una u otra forma va a ser visible en alguna parte del proceso.

Comment: Es posible encriptar javascript y html, pero para poder ser utilizado por el navegador tiene que ser desencriptado, hay un ejemplo de encriptar y desencriptar  en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172192/81450

Answer (score 1):

Para hablar de la [codifición porcentual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) primero hay que hablar de la especificación de [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) y su subyacente [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396)

> El esquema (URI) "http" es usado para localizar recursos de red a través del protocolo HTTP

Esto quiere decir que en el protocolo HTTP los recursos son solicitados a través de una URI.

Puesto que la direcciones son URIs, deben seguir las reglas especificadas en [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4)

> Los datos deben utilizar secuencias de escape si su representación contiene caracteres reservados; esto incluye datos que contienen un caracter no imprimible en el rango válido del conjunto de caracteres ASCII...

Como puedes ver, si el caracter no es imprimible o reservado, se debe utilizar una secuencia de escape para poder representarlo en el rango de caracteres ASCII imprimibles, cabe mencionar que caracteres como `"  "` y `"\n"` a pesar de ser imprimibles, estos deben ser representados utilizando secuencias de escapes.

La secuencia de escape se define como

> ```
>  escaped = "%" hex hex
>  hex     = digit | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" |
>                    "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f"
> ```

y esta debe contener el valor del caracter, así por ejemplo `" "` en la tabla ascii su valor (en hexadecimal) es `0x20` así que para poder representar el caracter `" "` este debe escribirse como `"%20"`

La implementación es algo trivial aquí te dejo mi implementación de `encodeURIComponent` (esta versión es minimalista y no acepta caracteres unicode)

```js
var codificar = ((function () {

var validos = ['-', '_', '.' , '!' , '~' , '*' , '\'' , '(' , ')']

return function codificar (texto) {
  if (typeof (texto) !== 'string') throw new TypeError('se esperaba una cadena de texto')
  var res = ''
  for (var c of texto) {
    if (esImprimible(c)) {
      res += c
      continue
    }
    if (code(c) > 127) throw new RangeError ('no se aceptan caracteres unicode')
    var _c = code(c).toString(16).toUpperCase()
    if (_c.length === 1) _c = '0' + _c
    res += '%' + _c
  }
  return res
}

function esImprimible (c) {
  return code(c) >= code('0') && code(c) <= code('9') ||
         code(c) >= code('a') && code(c) <= code('z') ||
         code(c) >= code('A') && code(c) <= code('Z') ||
         validos.indexOf(c) >= 0 
}

function code(c) {
  return c.codePointAt(0)
}

})())

var texto = 'hola/mundo#como-estan?'
console.log(codificar(texto))
console.log(encodeURIComponent(texto))
console.log('codificar = encodeURIComponent:', encodeURIComponent(texto) === codificar(texto))
```

**Nota**: Para soporte unicode primero se debería convertir el texto en un conjunto de bytes encodeados en utf-8 y convertir los respectivos bytes en secuencias de escapes, ya que el anterior código es ilustrativo, creo que agregar esa complejidad es contra producente, pero la idea intuitiva te la llevas.

Para decodificar el proceso es  el inverso, y la complejidad dependerá del conjunto de caracteres válidos, para ascii es trivial, para unicode se necesitaría hacer un paso más, como mencioné anteriormente.

Comment: Amigo y como se puede leer ese código `unescape` yo quisiera también poder saber lo que está codificado.

Comment: si solo quieres verlo utiliza la función `decodeURIComponent(...)`, es un `built-int` en los navegadores modernos